# Check at once the boolean values from a set of variables

Tags: python, boolean

I am having around 10 boolean variables, I need to set a new boolean variable `x=True` if all those ten variable values are True.If one of them is False then set `x= False` I can do this in a manner

```
if (a and b and c and d and e and f...):
    x = True
else:
    x=False
```

which obviously looks very ugly.Please suggest some more pythonic solutions.

The ugly part is `a and b and c and d and e and f...`

Comment: Also please note (as all the answers below suggest) that the `if`/`else` is unnecessary, just assign the value of the evaluation into `x` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have the bools in a list/tuple:

```
x = all(list_of_bools)
```

or just as suggested by @minopret

```
x= all((a, b, c, d, e, f))
```

example:

```
>>> list_of_bools = [True, True, True, False]
>>> all(list_of_bools)
False
>>> list_of_bools = [True, True, True, True]
>>> all(list_of_bools)
True
```

Comment: Should I create the list first then ? with all these variable

Comment: Right, you can just write a list or tuple inline: `all((a, b, c, d, e, f))`

Answer (score 1):

Although using `all` is the `one and preferably only obvious way to do it` in Python, here is another approach to do the same using the [and_](http://docs.python.org/library/operator#operator.and_) function from the [operator](http://docs.python.org/library/operator) module and reduce

```
>>> a = [True, True, False]
>>> from operator import and_
>>> reduce(and_, a)
False
>>> b = [True, True, True]
>>> reduce(and_, b)
True
```

**Edit:** As mentioned by Duncan, `and_` is the bitwise `&` operator and not the logical `and`. It will work only for boolean values as they will be casted to int (1 or 0)

Going by the comments, one should really use the BIF `all` to achieve what the OP has asked. I felt like adding this as an answer because I find it useful sometimes for eg, to build complex db queries in Django using Q objects and in some other cases.

Comment: -1 - hardly more _pythonic_ because it is much less readable than `all()`. Actually it is less readable than the chained `and`s

Comment: agreed that it's less pythonic as compared to `all()` but I think to any one who understands that `reduce` applies a function to two items of an iterable and reduces it 1 value, it should make perfect sense

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However not using `all()` is against at least 3 verses of the Zen of Python ...

Comment: Yes, I agree. Edited the answer

Comment: You should note in your answer that `and_` is the bitwise `&` operator, not the logical `and` operator. If the list really does contain booleans the only difference is that you get an `int` as the result instead of `bool`, but if it contains other values being used for their truth value you may get a completely different result. `reduce(and_, [1, 2, 3])` --> `0`, `all((1,2,3))` --> `True`.
Also, `all()` will short-circuit where your code won't.

Answer (score 1):

```
is_all_true = lambda *args:all(args)

a = True
b = True
c = True

print is_all_true(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = a and b and c and d and e ...
```

If it's something that would have to be calculated many times, consider using a function that gets all of the booleans (preferrably as a list or tuple, without assuming anything about its size).

Comment: and that function is called `all()`.