# Check multiple bool values with tuples in python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

```
bool_tuple = [(True, '123X'), (False, '734Y'), (False, '933Z')]
```

How can i check if all these values are True/False?
and I need to display the suitable failure message.

Suppose second item in list is failed then message should be :

```
"Item 734Y is failed"
"Item 933Z is failed"
```

How can i achieve the above scenario?

I know if its list with bool values its simpler, but how to handle bool values with tuples?

[Bool values with list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964979/check-at-once-the-boolean-values-from-a-set-of-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply iterate over the list:

```
>>> bool_tuple = [(True, '123X'), (False, '734Y'), (False, '933Z')]
for b, val in bool_tuple:
    if not b:
        print "Item {} failed".format(val)
...         
Item 734Y failed
Item 933Z failed
```

Where `b, val` is doing sequence unpacking, i.e for each item in `bool_tuple` assign the boolean value to `b` and the item to `val`

```
>>> b, val = (True, '123X')
>>> b
True
>>> val
'123X'
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's simple with Python generator comprehensions:

```
print "\n".join("Item %s failed" % item for flag, item in bool_tuple if not flag)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are implying  that when an item fails, then all items following it will also fail...
Simply break the first for loop and keep track of the position in the bool_tuple where you break at. Start another loop reading bool_tuple from the failed position to the end which will print the failure messages.